# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. in VB.net 2008

Tags: vb.net

I have been this problem for a week and searching every existing forum for an answer maybe this time that i post my own problem.

**acessdate is DateTimePicker Control  ,  barcodeno in Number ,  year in Number**

```vb
Private Sub btn_Save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Save.Click

    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

    If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.Open()
    End If

    'cmd.Connection = con

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Book_Entry (accessdate,barcodeno,accessno,callno,author,subject,title,edition,pub,publi_place,[year],pages,size,vendor,cost,remark) VALUES (@accessdate1,@barcodeno1,@accessno1,@callno1,@author1,@subject1,@title1,@edition1,@pub1,@publi_place1,@year1,@pages1,@size1,@vendor1,@cost1,@remark1)"
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accessdate1", DTPicker1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcodeno1", txt_BarCode.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accessno1", txt_Accession.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@callno1", txt_CallNo.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author1", txt_Author.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject1", cmb_Subject.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title1", txt_Title.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@edition1", txt_Edition.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pub", cmb_Publication.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@publi_place1", txt_PubliPlace.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year1", txt_Year.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pages1", txt_Pages.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@size1", txt_Size.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendor1", cmb_Vendor.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cost1", txt_Cost.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remark1", txt_Remark.Text)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Successfully Inserted", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure none of the values have a , or ' in them. Perhaps look to sanitise the input before running the command

Comment: @ChrisBint - that shouldn't matter if you are using a parameterized query

Comment: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement @Grim

Comment: My SQL-knowledge is rusty, but Will it not be a problem if you insert everything as text? I see quite a lot of entries which should be inserted as Integers. Feel free to educate me if I am wrong.

Comment: acessdate is DateTimePicker Control  ,  barcodeno in Number ,  year in Number

Comment: This is nothing to do with the values.  It's a syntax error in the SQL code so the SQL code is all that matters.  Most likely it's a reserved word issue.  Escape any of your column names that might be an issue, e.g. `size`, like you have done for `year`.

Comment: if `accessdate` is a Date column in the database, you are passing text to it by using `DTPicker1.Text` use `DTPicker1.Value` to get the **Date**. There might be others like Pages which might expect and integer.

Comment: I tried u said but no use :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if subject is a reserved name or not but in access using reserved names as field names will provide a syntax error.

In your case, change your 6th column's name from subject to anything else that isn't reserved and it will do the trick.

Otherwise, your query seems to be legit.

Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that OleDb support named parameters using the `@` notation. You should try using `?` instead for the query:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Book_Entry 
(accessdate,barcodeno,accessno,callno,author,subject,title,edition,pub,publi_place,[year],pages,size,vendor,cost,remark) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

Comment: If this is Jet/ACE OLE DB (which I assumed but now I see that it's not stated that Access is the database) then using names for parameters is supported, even though those names are ignored and only positions used to match values to place-holders.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is solved by using all in [] brackets
Thanks friends..**

`cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Book_Entry ([accessdate],[barcodeno],[accessno],[callno],[author],[hehehe],[title],[edition],[pub],[publi_place],[year2],[pages],[size],[vendor],[cost],[remark]) VALUES (@accessdate1,@barcodeno1,@accessno1,@callno1,@author1,@subject1,@title1,@edition1,@pub1,@publi_place1,@year1,@pages1,@size1,@vendor1,@cost1,@remark1)"
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accessdate1", DTPicker1.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcodeno1", txt_BarCode.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accessno1", txt_Accession.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@callno1", txt_CallNo.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author1", txt_Author.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject1", cmb_Subject.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title1", txt_Title.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@edition1", txt_Edition.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pub1", cmb_Publication.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@publi_place1", txt_PubliPlace.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year1", txt_Year.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pages1", txt_Pages.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@size1", txt_Size.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendor1", cmb_Vendor.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cost1", txt_Cost.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remark1", txt_Remark.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Successfully Inserted", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        con.Close()`